# How can I send a non-html-email in bold?

Tags: php, email

I want to send a simple email in php.
Is it possible to make the **Second Line of Text** in bold without using html mail?

```
<?php
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

Comment: You don't.  Plaintext e-mail is plaintext e-mail.

Comment: *"Is it possible...?"* Short answer: Not really.

Comment: You might look into PHPMailer class.  Makes html email super easy(which btw includes plaintext copies for older email clients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bold or format in any way inside a plain old text email (one which has a MIME type of `text/plain`).  That's why there is such a thing as HTML (MIME type of `text/html`) formating for email.

FYI, in setting the MIME type to HTML is specified by `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`